# after matching pattern how to add dash after string in perl.regex

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

i have this type of data:
please help me out i am new to regular expressions,and please explain each step while answering.thanks..

```
7210315_AX1A_1X50_LI_MOTORTRAEGER_VORN_AUSSEN

7210316_W1A_1X50_RE_MOTORTRAEGER_VORN_AUSSEN

7210243_U1A_1X50_LI_MOTORTRAEGER_VORN_INNEN

7210330_AV21NA_ABSTUETZUNG_STUETZTRAEGER_RAD
```

i want to extract only this data from above lines:

```
7210315_AX1A_MOTORTRAEGER_VORN_AUSSEN

7210316_W1A_MOTORTRAEGER_VORN_AUSSEN

7210243_U1A_MOTORTRAEGER_VORN_INNEN

7210330_AV21NA_ABSTUETZUNG_STUETZTRAEGER_RAD
```

then if *AX1A* contains two consecutive alphabets after underscore ,it should be written as AX_ , and if contains single digit and single alphabet then they become as -1_ and -A_ so after applying this pattern it will become: AX_-1_-A_ and all other data should be remain same.

similarly in next line "W1A" so firstly it contains single alphabet "W" which should be converted to -W_  now next character is a single digit so it should also be converted as same pattern -1_ similarly last one is also treated same.so it become -W_-1_-A_

we are only interested in applying regex to the part after digits followed by underscore.

```
_AX1A_

_W1A_

_U1A_

_AV21NA_
```

output should be:

```
7210315_AX_-1_-A_MOTORTRAEGER_VORN_AUSSEN

7210316_-W_-1_-A_MOTORTRAEGER_VORN_AUSSEN

7210243_-U_-1_-A_MOTORTRAEGER_VORN_INNEN

7210330_AV_21_NA_ABSTUETZUNG_STUETZTRAEGER_RAD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $match 
    = qr/
    ( \d+          # group of digits
      _            # followed by an underscore
    )              # end group
    ( \p{Alpha}+ ) # group of alphas             
    ( \d+ )        # group of digits
    ( \p{Alpha}* ) # group of alphas
    ( \w+ )        # group of word characters
    /x
    ;

while ( my $record = <$input> ) { # record of input
    # match and capture
    if ( my ( $pre, $pre_alpha, $num, $post_alpha, $post ) = $record =~ m/$match/ ) {
        say $pre 
             # if the alpha has length 1, add a dash before it
          . ( length $pre_alpha == 1 ? '-' : '' )
            # then the alpha
          . $pre_alpha
            # then the underscore
          . '_'
            # test if the length of the number is 1 and the length of the 
            # trailing alpha string is 1 
          . ( length( $num ) == 1 && length( $post_alpha ) == 1
              # if true, apply a dash before each 
            ? "-$num\_-$post_alpha" 
              # otherwise treat as AV21NA in example.
            : "$num\_$post_alpha"
            )
          . $post
          ;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know all the ins and outs of what you need stripped, but I'll extrapolate and let you clarify if this doesn't do quite what you need.

For the first step, extracting the `1X50_RE_` and `1X50_LI`, you could search for those strings and replace them with nothing.

Next, to split your second letter/number code into your small chunks, you can use a pair of matches, using a look-ahead on each. However, since you only want to mess with that second code chunk, I'd split the overall line up first, work on the second chunk, and then join the pieces back together again.

```
while (<$input>) {

    # Replace the 1X50_RE/LI_ bits with nothing (i.e., delete them)
    s/1X50_(RE|LI)_//;

    my @pieces = split /_/; # split the line into pieces at each underscore

    # Just working with the second chunk. /g, means do it for all matches found
    $pieces[1] =~ s/([A-Z])(?=[0-9])/$1_-/g; # Convert AX1 -> AX_-1
    $pieces[1] =~ s/([0-9])(?=[A-Z])/$1_-/g; # Convert 1A -> 1-_A

    # Join the pieces back together again
    $_ = join '_', @pieces;

    print;
}
```

The `$_` is the variable many Perl operations work on if you don't specify. The `<$input>` reads the next line of the file handle named `$input` into `$_`. The `s///`, `split`, and `print` functions work on `$_` when not given. The `=~` operator is the way you tell Perl to use `$pieces[1]` (or whichever variable you are working on) instead of `$_` for regular expression operations. (For `split` or `print`, you'd pass the variables as the argument instead, so `split /_/` is the same as `split /_/, $_` and `print` is the same as `print $_`.)

Oh, and to explain the regular expressions a bit:

```
s/1X50_(RE|LI)_//;
```

This is matching anything containing `1X50_RE` or `1X50_LI` (the `(|)` is a list of alternatives) and replacing them with nothing (the empty `//` at the end).

Looking at one of the other lines:

```
s/([A-Z])(?=[0-9])/$1_-/g;
```

The plain parentheses `(...)` around `[A-Z]` cause `$1` to be set to whatever letter is matched inside (in this case a letter, A-Z). The `(?=...)` parenthesis cause a zero-width positive look-ahead assertion. That means the regular expression only matches if the very next thing in the string matches the expression (a digit, 0-9), but that part of the match is not included as part of the string that is replaced.

The `/$1_-/` causes the matched part of the string, the `[A-Z]`, to be replaced with the value captured by the parentheses, `(...)`, but before the look-head, `[0-9]`, with the addition of the `_-` you require.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure like this:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    s/1X50_(LI|RE)_//;
    s/(\d+)_([A-Z])(\d)([A-Z])/$1_-$2_-$3_-$4/;
    s/(\d+)_([A-Z]{2})(\d)([A-Z])/$1_$2_-$3_-$4/;
    s/(\d+)_([A-Z]{1,2})(\d+)([A-Z]+)/$1_$2_$3_$4/;
    print;
}

__DATA__
7210315_AX1A_1X50_LI_MOTORTRAEGER_VORN_AUSSEN
7210316_W1A_1X50_RE_MOTORTRAEGER_VORN_AUSSEN
7210243_U1A_1X50_LI_MOTORTRAEGER_VORN_INNEN
7210330_AV21NA_ABSTUETZUNG_STUETZTRAEGER_RAD
```

output:

```
7210315_AX_-1_-A_MOTORTRAEGER_VORN_AUSSEN
7210316_-W_-1_-A_MOTORTRAEGER_VORN_AUSSEN
7210243_-U_-1_-A_MOTORTRAEGER_VORN_INNEN
7210330_AV_21_NA_ABSTUETZUNG_STUETZTRAEGER_RAD
```

Comment: i want this output: single character or digit should be replaced with _-9_-A and double character or digit should be AB_43_            7210315_AX_-1_-A_MOTORTRAEGER_VORN_AUSSEN                                                                                                                    7210316_-W_-1_-A_MOTORTRAEGER_VORN_AUSSEN                                  7210330_AV_21_NA_ABSTUETZUNG_STUETZTRAEGER_RAD

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
while (<>) {
    next if /^\s*$/;
    chomp;
    ## Remove those parts of the line we do not want
    ## You do not specify what, if anything, is constant about
    ## the parts you do not want. One of the following cases should
    ## serve.

    ## i) Remove the string _1X50_ and the next characters between
    ## two underscores:
    s/_1X50_.+?_/_/;

    ## ii) keep the first 2 and last 3 sections of each line.
    ## Uncomment this line and comment the previous one to use this:
    #s/^(.+?_.+?)_.+_(.+_.+_.+)$/$1_$2/;

    ## The line now contains only those regions we are 
    ## interested in. Split on '_' to collect an array of the
    ## different parts (@a):
    my @a=split(/_/);

    ## $a[1] is the second string, eg AX1A,W1A etc.
    ## We search for one or more letters, followed by one or more digits
    ## followed by one or more letters. The 'i' operand makes the match
    ## case Insensitive and the 'g' operand makes the search global, allowing
    ## us to capture the matches in the @matches array. 
    my @matches=($a[1]=~/^([a-z]*)(\d*)([a-z]*)/ig);

    ## So, for each of the matched strings, if the length of the match
    ## is less than 2, add a '-' to the beginning of the string:
    foreach my $match (@matches) {
        if (length($match)<2) {
        $match="-" . $match;
        }
    }
    ## Now replace the original $a[1] with each string in
    ## @matches, connected by '_':
    $a[1]=join("_", @matches);

    ## Finally, build the string $kk by joining each element
    ## of the line (@a) by a '_', and print:
    my $kk=join("_", @a);
    print "$kk\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

zostay's suggestion of splitting the line may make things easier if you are a regex beginner.  However, avoiding the split is optimal from a performance perspective.  Here is how to do it without splitting:

```
open IN_FILE, "filename" or die "Whoops!  Can't open file.";
while (<IN_FILE>)
{
     s/^\d{7}_\K([A-Z]{1,2})(\d{1,2})([A-Z]{1,2})/-${1}-${2}-${3}/ 
          or print "line didn't match: $line\n";
     s/1X50_(LI|RE)_//;
}
```

Breaking down the first pattern:
`s///` is the search-and-replace operator.
`^` match the beginning of the line
`\d{7}_` match seven digits, followed by an underscore
`\K` look-behind operator.  This means that whatever came before won't be part of the string that is replaced. `()` each set of parentheses specifies a chunk of the match that will be captured.  These will be put into the match variables $1, $2, etc. in order. `[A-Z]{1,2}` this means match between one and two capital letters.  You can probably figure out what the other two sections in parentheses mean. `-${1}-${2}-${3}` Replace what matched with the first three match variables, preceded by dashes.  The only reason for the curly braces is to  make clear what the variable name is.

Comment: s/^\d{7}_\K([A-Z]{1,2})(\d{1,2})([A-Z]{1,2})/-${1}-${2}-${3}/